# Deep Copying Error

Tags: java, deep-copy

Dea All,

I have the following:

```
class test {
    int x = 6;
    int y = 7;

    private int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    private int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public test copy() {
        test myTest = new test();
        myTest.x = getX();
        myTest.y = getY();
        return myTest;
    }
}
```

However, when I then execute:

```
test a = new test();
test b = a.copy();
b.x = 17;
System.out.println(a.x);
```

The result is still 17. However, shouldn't deep copying prevent this?

Anybody who can help me?

Comment: Prints `6` for me, both the original and revised code.

Comment: It is really hard to help you when you ask "Why does my code do X?", when in fact it does **not** do X.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are ignoring the return value of `b.copy()` in:

```
test b = new test();
b.copy();
```

Secondly, I've tested your code and it prints `6` and not `17` as you say in the question.

**edit** I notice that you've fixed the first issue in an edit. However, the code still doesn't behave the way you say it does.

Comment: Third: that isn't even deep copy ;-)

Comment: @ITroubs: I was going to say something about this, but then decided it was deep *enough* ;)

Comment: Yeah, the last edit he made to the post fixes the bug and it now returns 17.  It didn't originally have the same code.

Answer (score 0):

The result should be 6 not 17.